# objectinputstream override resolveclass

Tags: java

i am using example code @ https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-lookahead/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InvalidClassException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectStreamClass;
import java.security.SignedObject

public class LookAheadObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    public LookAheadObjectInputStream(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        if (!desc.getName().equals(SignedObject.class.getName())) {
            throw new InvalidClassException(
                    "Unauthorized deserialization attempt",
                    desc.getName());
        }
        return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }
}
```

However, is it possible to use instanceof to compare?
I like to change
if (!desc.getName().equals(SignedObject.class.getName()))
to
if(!desc(something here) instanceof SignedObject)

unfortunately, i can't instanceof comparison correctly

Comment: `ObjectStreamClass` is only a descriptor containing the `serialVersionUID` and the class name. Since it is not an instance of the class you cannot use `instanceof`.